# Should we still use em for font sizes now that most/all new browsers implement page zooming by default?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Font sizes: EMs vs Pixels… in 2011, which one should be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183733/font-sizes-ems-vs-pixels-in-2011-which-one-should-be-used)

I've started to read on the net that all browsers are implementing page zoom by default, not text enlarge.

I've also read a PrestaShop theming tutorial the other day that said...

> Don't use ems anymore, thanks to page zooming. Use pixels for font sizes.

I'm not sure I necessarily agree, but with the `body { font-size: 62.5% }` for ease of em sizing, should we begin to phase out em sizing for pixels?

Comment: I had the same question after I noticed that frameworks like Blueprint CSS do all their sizing in pixels...

Comment: @RobinWinslow Maybe so, but that was asked after mine, so it's a duplicate of mine.

Comment: Fair point. It does have the better answer though.

Comment: @alex Your question was current a year ago. The new question is, well, newer so it makes more sense to link yours to a more current version rather than the other way around.

Comment: @AnnaLear What about the wording below *This question covers exactly the same ground as **earlier questions** on this topic...* Does this also mean I can ask this same question in a year's time and close the other one because my new question is newer? That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I agree that the wording doesn't really apply in this case, but why would closing the newer, current version of this as a duplicate of your question be better? In any case, if you disagree with the closure, feel free to bring it up on [meta] and see which way community swings. Thanks.

Comment: @AnnaLear I'm always in favour of a merge, myself.

Answer (score 2):

Pixel sizing can be more accurate, but scales to high resolutions and DPI badly. Browser AA does offset this somewhat.

Read [Page Zoom, Elastic Layouts & Em](http://dialdfordesign.com/?p=185) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

pixels for fonts is a bad idea. Your site will look crap on high dpi displays, and high density displays for the desktop are on the horizon (and are already on many mobile devices).

Comment: I always thought pixel sizing was bad because it didn't resize in all browsers.

Comment: 1 css pixel is not necessary 1 screen pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Using em sizing has no negative effects for modern browsers, and removing it could create negative effects for old ones.

From a another perspective: I've found using em's much more restrictive which doesn't allow me to fiddle as much.

Additionally, desktop sized screens are not the only interface to the web. But, small devices are used to making good guesses. Therefore, I don't know if that's much of a concern.