# How do i make font-size unchangeable?

Tags: html, css, font-size

When i change font-size in browser settings (e.g. Google Chrome) to very large, most websites's font-size changes accordingly.(including SO)

But there're sites that don't change their font-size at all!!
(or don't change entirely)

Google is the case in point. Its home page isnt changed at all!!
Its SERP changed **only** results' font-size!

The question is : how should i markup webpages (html/css)
to make their font-size unchangeable??

Comment: Google's font changes size....?

Comment: You shouldn't really want to do this. You have the chance of making your site unusable for people with poor eyesight, there's a reason this has been implemented in browsers.

Comment: How do you increase just the font-size in chrome?  I know IE has an option for that but I thought chrome just had zoom.

Comment: @locrizak No. i meant, Google SERP page's font-size is partially changed - Google Chrome, according to my settings, changed font-size to very large, but on Google SERP only results'font-size was changed..

Comment: @kingjiv Wrench menu - options - under the hood- web content- font-size

Comment: @DrStrangeLove they change the same for me on that page as well

Answer (score 1):

The websites that don't change font sizes on user interaction generally use `em` or `%` unit declarations in their stylesheets. One thing you can do is to explicitly use `px` or `pt` which would prevent most (unexperienced) users from scaling.

Keep in mind, though, that you will lose all the benefits that come with dynamic font-sizes like smooth fluid layouts, inheritance (done right this is a major time and problem saver) and last but not least user satisfaction (who is to decide how I am supposed to read a website other than me anyway?).

You may also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183733/font-sizes-ems-vs-pixels-in-2011-which-one-should-be-used).

Comment: for instance, this page's (http://proverstka.ru/bizedu/index.html) font-size is also not enlarged.. Why??